# Изменить папку с репозиториями на сервере

Tags: git, git-remote

Сейчас все репозиории на удаленном сервере лежат в домашней папке пользователя (`/home/git`). Чтобы сделать clone на локальной машине, пишем

```
git clone git@srv:test.git
```

Есть желание перенести репозитории из папки `/home/git` в `/home/git/repo`, но тогда нужно будет писать

```
git clone git@srv:repo/test.git
```

И во всех проектах на локальных машинах нужно будет изменить

```
remote.origin.url=git@srv:test.git
```

на

```
remote.origin.url=git@srv:repo/test.git
```

Есть ли возможность обойтись без изменений на локальных машинах?

Comment: Я ответа не знаю, но в работе иногда использую GitLab (https://about.gitlab.com/). Можно легко поднять на сервере, а сам гитлаб предоставляет репозитории по веб ссылкам(https://srv/repo.git), что очень таки удобно

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)